# Ajax call in JSF 2.2 for dynamically created rows in DATATABLE

Tags: jsf-2.2

Iam dynamically creating new rows  in dataTable by clicking on ADD ROW button in jsf 2.2. I need to do ajax call to particular column. Iam invoking AJAX action method but the values are not passing to backing bean.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide code so as we get a better grasp of what is wrong?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and https://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question. Oh and start with [tour]